# How to fix corrupted bash-completion in command substitution?

Tags: bash, bashrc

it seems my `bash-completion` got corrupted. Every time I try to use command substitution, for example when I type

```
ls $(ls Deskto<Tab>
```

..result is..

```
ls $(ls Desktobash unexpected eof while looking for matching ")".
```

I tried removing my `.bashrc` file and `cp /etc/skel/bashrc ~/` to get a new one. That works until I add something into my new bashrc. Even when I do `echo '#" >> ./.bashrc` it breaks again. Removing my `bash_aliases` did not help either.

Also `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion` did not do the trick. 
However there are some threads about similar problem, nothing works.

ANY hint will be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bash-completion` isn't really "corrupted" - this is simply [a known bug](https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/?func=detail&aid=314667&group_id=100114&atid=413095) with bash-completion 2.1 and Bash 4.3.

I recently answered [a related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571544/bash-tab-completion-bash-unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching-bash/576983#576983) over at AskUbuntu and [then again right here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152328/bash-tab-completion-fails-inside-of-command-substitution/180673#180673), but since I'm at it I'll also answer here so that people googling for this problem will find the answer here too.

I gave more details [over at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571544/bash-tab-completion-bash-unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching-bash/576983#576983), but essentially, to fix it, you can:

1. Replace

   ```
   [[ ${!2} == \$* ]] && eval $2=${!2}
   ```

   with

   ```
   [[ ${!2} == \$\'* ]] && eval $2=${!2}
   ```

   in the function `_quote_readline_by_ref` in the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` (not recommended); or
2. Check out the newest Git version of [the bash-completion library](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) and use that - the bug seems to be fixed in this version.

You won't get tab completion inside command substitution working again with either of these solutions, but at least, you won't see that error message any longer.

To actually get tab completion inside command substitution working, you will either have to revert to an earlier Bash version ([where I hear it was working](https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/?func=detail&aid=314667&group_id=100114&atid=413095)), or wait for the library to truly fix that issue with Bash 4.3.

Comment: Wow, I have almost lost hope this bug will ever be fixed. THANK YOU very much, it was annoying and now it is working again :)

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can cause this is aliasing the `local` keyword; avoid aliasing keywords like `local`, `do`, `done`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this- I had aliased "local"- fixed my problem exactly!

Answer (score 1):

First I'd look in `/etc/bash_completion` It should look like

```
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

(don't miss the `.` in the start of line)
If it did not help I'll try to find all links in bash files

```
find / -name *bash* -type f -exec grep -l completion {} \+ 2>/dev/null
```

and check it for mistakes. In some file should be following code

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checked /etc/bash_completion and it is all right. The find command found 25 files but none of them seems corrupted to me (as far as I can say..I was searching for some missing fi but did not find any). The code is in the .bashrc file and also looks just fine. :/

Comment: The thing is that main action is calling `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` but if you reinstall it that everything should be correct. You can try fully remove it by `purge` and then install it again, but I don't sure that is help.

Comment: I have tried to purge and install again, but the problem still persist. Very annoying issue :/

Comment: Let see what is in your `.bashrc`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/h1m5pfV0 here's my `.bashrc`. It is a brand new one from `/etc/skel` with '#' at the end. Every time I add something (for example the '#' sing) the bash-completion breaks.

Comment: @loomingShade It looks with nothing unusual. So let start with unusual advices: if your add to the file not in the last line but somewhere in the middle for example? If you make the last line empty (add more 1 after `#`) ?

Comment: Oh so I just found out that even unedited brand new `.bashrc` file from `/etc/skel` breaks bash-completion.

Comment: If you delete $HOME/.bashrc at all do bash-completition work?

Comment: Yes. It is odd. When I delete `$HOME/.bashrc`, everything works just fine. However everytime I `cp` a new one, it breaks.

Comment: (not sure if useful information, but I just discovered)..when I have `.bashrc` file in my $HOME, my console window is named **loomingshade@loomingshade-ThinkPad-T400**. When I delete the file, the name changes to **/bin/bash**. Also (maybe could be useful) my Default terminal is terminator (not gnome-terminal).